# Why does animating border radius to zero requires that all four values be equal to zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I have this element:

```
<div id="transform"> </div>
```

Css is :

```
#transform {
left:0px;
top:0px;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: green ;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

I want to animate border radius from 0 to 100 and back to 0 and its former position:

```
 $("#transform").click(function  () {
   $(this).animate({

    left:500,
    borderRadius:100

    },1000,function  () {
      $(this).animate({

        left:0,
        borderRadius:0

    },1000);
  })
});
```

First function works well and animates movement and changing border radius over one second to 100px, but the other one immediately changes border radius to 0 and then moves back to its former position over one second. Shouldn't border radius as well change to zero over one second? Isn't it logical?
So I changed second function to :

```
 $("#transform").click(function  () {
   $(this).animate({
      left:500,
      borderRadius:100

      },1000,function  () {
       $(this).animate({
        left:0,
        borderTopLeftRadius:0, 
        borderTopRightRadius:0, 
        borderBottomLeftRadius:0,  
        borderBottomRightRadius:0
    },1000);
  });
});
```

And everything worked well and over one second.
Can someone tell me why is this required when changing border radius to 0 only and not when changing to some other value as well?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2o08tt81/**

Comment: ...and FF35..and IE11

Comment: Could it be Firefox issue then? I only used it in Firefox and I'm using Ubuntu. Ok so FF working , then it has something to do with Ubuntu...

Comment: I doesn't work on mine, FF 35.0.1 but fine in chrome.

Comment: @Syahrul Thanks for feedback , so it is FF somehow... what OS are you using so I can rule out Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using OSX Yosimete

Comment: @Paulie_D What OS are you using? It doesnt work in FF for me , but i just tested it in Chromium and it works.. so it has to be FF